# Cannot read propery 'cpf' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a file, which im using to create an object, so i can store it on my database firestore. I am importing this file to my register page, and using ngModels to grab the values passed by the user. So, to do that, i instantiated my data object inside my register page and create a variable called Usuario to hold the object inside my file.

Here's my object.

```
export const dados = {

    Documento: {
        cpf: "",
        sus: "",
        data_nasc: "",
        email: "",
        rep_email: "",
        telefone: "",
        senha: "",
        rep_senha: ""
    }
};
```

Then, i import my file.

```
import * as meusDados from '../interface/paciente.interface';
```

Then how i instantiate my meusDados class.

```
export class CadastroPage {

Usuario = meusDados;

}
```

Then how i store my data from HTML

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>CPF</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.cpf"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Cartão SUS - CNS</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.sus"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Data de nascimento</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.data_nasc"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>E-mail</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Confirmação de e-mail</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.rep_email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Telefone celular com DDD</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.telefone"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.senha"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Repita a senha senha</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.Documento.rep_senha"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

Whenever i try to click my button to do the registering i receive the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cpf' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

```
export const dados = {

    Documento: {
        cpf: "",
        sus: "",
        data_nasc: "",
        email: "",
        rep_email: "",
        telefone: "",
        senha: "",
        rep_senha: ""
    }
};
```

Since you are doing import *, you are not importing just that constant. You are importing everything from that file. So:

```
Usuario = meusDados;
```

Is not doing what you think it is doing. It should be:

```
Usuario = meusDados.dados;
```

Also, I don't think you have a valid constant. I think what you are looking for is:

```
export const dados: Documento = {   
        cpf: "",
        sus: "",
        data_nasc: "",
        email: "",
        rep_email: "",
        telefone: "",
        senha: "",
        rep_senha: ""
};

import { dados } from '../interface/paciente.interface';

Usario = dados;
```

Then, you would do:

```
<ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="Usuario.cpf"></ion-input>
```

Comment: it returns Documento is undefined when i say dados is of type Documento...

Comment: You have to import that interface/class before you can use it in that file.

Comment: I mean, i assume you meant that i should  change export const dados = { Documento: { to   export const dados: Documento = {, inside my interface class. Because if so, thats triggering the error saying Documento is undefined

Comment: Yes. It will be undefined if you don't import it into the pacient.interface file. That file needs to import { Document } from 'wherever', otherwise it will be undefined

Comment: in-fact i apologize, it says cannot find name 'Documento'. Not undefined

Comment: also, i might misunderstood what you were trying to say, but i think you're saying i should declare my object inside my CadastroPage and then import it inside my interface file? If that's the case, what i am trying to do is exactly the opposite